# Using 'this' in String.prototype

Tags: javascript

For various javascript applications, I frequently use a little function I wrote called isBlank():

```
isBlank = function(text) {
    while(text[0] == ' ') text = text.substr(1);
    return (text === '');
}
```

All this function does is remove all the space from the begining of the input string, and then returns true or false if the result is blank or not.  So I tried to make this function into a String prototype as follows:

```
String.prototype.isBlank = function() {
    while(this[0] == ' ') this = this.substr(1);
    return (this === '');       
}
```

However, the prototype version gives an "Invalid left hand assignment" error when you try something like:

```
"      ".isBlank();

ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I imagine this issue stems from the fact that I am reassigning the 'this' object in the while loop, but since I am still learning java script I was wondering if someone would be able to give a more detailed explanation of why this prototype doesn't work.  I am more interested in the theory side of this question, and not so much interested in how to make the isBlank() function into a string prototype that does what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you want compatibility, you should be using `this.charAt(0)` as `this[0]` isn't supported in older versions of IE.

Comment: It's much shorter to use a `RegExp` test: `String.prototype.isBlank = function () {return /^ *$/.test(this)}`, although you might want to include checks for other characters, such as `\n`, `\r`, `\f`, and `\t`.

Answer (score 3):

You can not reassign this. That is what the error is saying.

[ECMAScript spec](http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-10.html).

> **10.1.7 This**
>
> There is a this value associated with every active execution context.
>   The this value depends on the caller and the type of code being
>   executed and is determined when control enters the execution context.
>   The this value associated with an execution context is immutable.

Another link [explaining this](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-3-this/)

Comment: I can't find a section 10.1.7?

Comment: @Bergi It's from 3rd Edition. For 5th, [10.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.3) and/or [11.1.1](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.1).

Comment: LOL, guess I need to update my cheatsheet I have with old notes.

Answer (score 2):

You can never assign to the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). If you want to assign, you will need to create an extra variable, like so:

```
String.prototype.isBlank = function() {
    var text = this;
    while(text[0] == ' ') text = text.substr(1);
    return (text === '');       
}
```

Btw: Not all browsers do support accessing single characters via bracket notation, you should use [`.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt). Also, a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) sometimes makes live easier:

```
String.prototype.isBlank = function() {
    return /^ *$/.test(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.isBlank = function() {
    return (this.trim() === '');       
}
```